# CallLogs - which column to use in KitKat+ versions to track calls made through a specific Account ?

Tags: android, calllog

In Jellybean, there was a column "account_name" which I was using to store my app Tag and retrieve all calls made through my app. However in Kitkat and later, that column is missing. Which column can I use to store my Account name ? The documentation does not seem clear enough to me.

Appreciate your help.